# Removing products from cart and checkout

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, cart

I have a helper that in the click of the button, according to the id of the product it adds the same to the stand.

But I need to do the reverse, a function that removed a product from the cart according to its product id on button click.

I search a lot about it, but I still did not find anything that could help me do the function to remove the product from the cart.

**Edit: I tried this function below, but it removes all the products that are in the cart, not just the product according to its id.**

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();        
foreach ($items as $item) 
{
   $itemId = $item->getItemId();
   $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
}
```

**Note: The above code is in a controller.**

**Ajax request code:**

```
function removeCartaotoCart(){
                $j.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/removeCartao') ?>",
                    data:{

                    },
                    cache: false,
                    beforeSend: function(){
                        alert("beforeSend");
                    },
                    success: function(){
                        alert("Sucess removeCartao");
                    },
                    complete: function () {
                        alert("complete removeCartaotoCart");
                    },
                    error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
                });
            }
```

**Edit 2:**

**Button code:**

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo Mage::helper('core')->quoteEscape($this->__('Add to Cart')) ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="addCartao('<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>')" name="cartaoMensagem<?php echo $_product->getId(); ?>"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

**Ajax request that adds the product to the cart and change the button text / Address the second request of which the code is above (this request is not so important in this question, but for information, I also put it):**

```
function addCartao(product_id){
                $j.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: "<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/addCartao') ?>",
                  data: {
                    product_id: product_id
                  },
                  dataType: 'json',
                  cache : false,
                  beforeSend: function () {

                  },
                  success: function (retorno) {
                    var button = $j('button[name=cartaoMensagem' + product_id + ']');

                  if($j(button).text() == 'Comprar'){
                    $j('#cartao').find(':button').not(button).attr('disabled',true);
                    $j(button).html('<span>Remover</span>');
                    $j('.item-custom').append('<tr id="trAppend"><td class="a-center lc-thumbnails"><img src="' + retorno['imagem'] + '" width="50" height="50" alt="' + retorno['name'] + '"></td><td><h3 class="product-name">' + retorno['name'] + '</h3></td><td class="a-center">1</td><td class="a-right"><span class="cart-price"><span class="price"> R$ ' + retorno['price'] + '</span></span></td></tr>');
                    getSubTotal();
                    getGrandTotal();
                  } else{
                    $j('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',false);
                    $j(button).html('<span>Comprar</span>');
                    $j('.item-custom #trAppend').remove();
                    removeCartaotoCart();
                    getSubTotal();
                    getGrandTotal();
                  }

                  },
                  complete: function () {

                  },
                  error: function (x,y,z) {
                    alert("error");
                    alert(x);
                    alert(y);
                    alert(z);
                    window.location.reload();
                    history.go(0);
                    window.location.href=window.location.href;
                  }
              });
            }
```

Comment: Can you add the JS code or PHP action code where you are using this code?

Comment: Yes I can. I'll add

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like below.

First update your `removeCartaotoCart` function and pass the item id to remove as an argument.

```
function removeCartaotoCart(itemId){
    $j.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"<?php echo Mage::getUrl('fol_carousel/ajax/removeCartao') ?>/itemId/"+itemId,
        data:{

        },
        cache: false,
        beforeSend: function(){
            alert("beforeSend");
        },
        success: function(){
            alert("Sucess removeCartao");
        },
        complete: function () {
            alert("complete removeCartaotoCart");
        },
        error: function (x,y,z) {
        alert("error");
        alert(x);
        alert(y);
        alert(z);
        window.location.reload();
        history.go(0);
        window.location.href=window.location.href;
      }
    });
}
```

Now update your PHP code to get that Id and remove the item matching the id.

```
$cartHelper = Mage::helper('checkout/cart');
$items = $cartHelper->getCart()->getItems();
$productId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('itemId');
foreach ($items as $item) 
{
    if ($item->getProductId() == $productId) {
       $itemId = $item->getItemId();
       $cartHelper->getCart()->removeItem($itemId)->save();
    }
}
```

Update below code in your `addCartao` function

```
else{
    $j('#cartao').find(':button').attr('disabled',false);
    $j(button).html('<span>Comprar</span>');
    $j('.item-custom #trAppend').remove();
    removeCartaotoCart(product_id); // Pass Product ID here
    getSubTotal();
    getGrandTotal();
}
```

Comment: It did not work out and as I am using the magento own buy button, when I click and call this function, instead of removing the product, it adds another.

Comment: @MatheusPortela, How are you using Buy button to remove a product? Can you please add the code for the button too in your question?

Comment: Yes, I can add yes. The next thing happens, when the Buy button is clicked, its text changes to remove and the product is added to the cart. What I wanted to do is when the button with the remove text was clicked, the same product was removed.

Comment: I updated the question with all the information.

Comment: @MatheusPortela, I have updated my answer, please check

Comment: Jaimin, it still did not work, it does not remove the product and still adds another to the cart.

Comment: I do not know why, but if I pass the parameters by url it removes the product from the cart, but if those same parameters are passed by the request, the product is not removed.

Comment: Jaimin, I updated your answer with a code syntax correction that is required for the button to also send the parameters to the controller.